# Negative threshold in roc_curve and precision_recall_curve

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to find optimal threshold that can differentiate the two classes well but i am getting negative thresholds using `roc_curve` and `precision_recall_curve`.

I have build a CNN-LSTM architecture. I am not sure if these information are enough to find the solution, but i want to know what would be the first thing you will check if you get negative threshold.

Here are the functions

```
 def optimal_threshold_precision_recall_curve(self,gt, pmap):
    """Function to return an optimal thresholding value of the image
    """
    gt = gt.flatten()
    pmap = pmap.flatten()
    precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(gt,pmap, pos_label=1)
    optimal_thresholds = sorted(list(zip(np.abs(precision - recall), thresholds)), key=lambda i: i[0], reverse=False)[0][1]
    # optimal_mask = np.where(pmap>optimal_thresholds,1,0)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(recall,precision)
    plt.savefig('test.png')
    return optimal_thresholds
```

```
def auc_thresh(self,label, pred,mode):
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(label.flatten(), pred.flatten())
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    gmeans = np.sqrt(tpr * (1-fpr))
    ix = np.argmax(gmeans)
    print('Best %s Threshold=%f, G-Mean=%.3f' % (mode,thresholds[ix], gmeans[ix]))
    return thresholds[ix]
```

This is how graph look like, code to plot this image is `optimal_threshold_precision_recall_curve` function
[image]

Comment: You probably have a bug in your code or the values you are showing are not what you assume them to be. Without access to your code and data it is not possible to help.